# 2 font files in css, one works but the other does not

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-face

I have 2 font files: Gotham-Book.ttf and HelveticaNeue-Thin.otf. Helvetica works fine but Gotham does not.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Thin';
   src:asset-url('HelveticaNeue-Thin.otf');
   src:font-url('HelveticaNeue-Thin.otf');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Gotham-Book';
   src:asset-url('Gotham-Book.ttf');
   src:font-url('Gotham-Book.ttf');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Gotham-Book', 'HelveticaNeue-Thin';
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

Both files are in the same folder.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should work! It is how I have always declared my fonts in CSS3.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontName";
    src: url(FontName.extension);
}
```

This is if they are in your root folder. If it was to exist in another folder it would be:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontName";
    src: url(/folder/FontName.extension);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for the web, some recommendations:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
   src: url('HelveticaNeue-Thin.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Two things to note: `src` takes urls, and they use `url(...)`, not `font-url` or `asset-url`, and ideally, a format indicator to make it clear that you know what you're trying to load. Also, no need to mention weight and style if they're normal, since those are the defaults.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham Book';
  src: url('Gotham-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Again, a format hint is good. And finally:

```
body
{
  font-family: 'Gotham Book', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

Have a font stack, so your content has sensible fallbacks, in case things go wrong. Without a stack like this, you're probably going to end up with Times/Times New Roman on font resource failure, which isn't even a sans-serif font. It'll look much worse than with "the wrong" but still sans-serif sequence of fallbacks.

On a design note, though, you're doing something odd: Gotham Book is *much* thicker than Helvetica Neue Thin, so pretending that a "Thin" font is actually font-weight "normal" and perfectly interchangeable for Gotham Book is curious. It makes far more sense to say this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
   src: url('HelveticaNeue-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
   font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
   src: url('HelveticaNeue-Thin.otf') format('opentype');
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

and then be explicit about the font-weight in your actual styling:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Gotham Book';
}
p {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-weight: 400; /* will use ...-Regular source */
}
p.thin {
  font-weight: 300; /* will use ...-Thin source */
}
```

Finally, if you want to support the most browsers, don't use the ttf/otf sources, but convert them to WOFF. It's more of a "wrapper" than a conversion, but it increases the platform support tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `font-url()` or `asset-url()`, make sure the css file have `.css.scss` extension if you are using Rails as they need processing before they are served.